# Dimension doesn't applied to Lookup window sum calculation

Tags: tableau-api

I'm new to Tableau so please forgive me if I'm not asking this question the way it should. I hope you will understand me anyway.

I have he following table :

```
date(dd/mm/yy),country,postid
01/01/17, us, xxxx
01/01/17, fr, xxxx
02/01/17, fr, xxxx
02/01/17, us, xxxx
02/01/17, us, xxxx
03/01/17, fr, xxxx
etc...
```

so I have a calculated field like this one which is 'Nb of posts' :

```
if [Country]="us" THEN 1 else 0 END
```

Then I have the following formula 'Last 7 days' :

```
LOOKUP(WINDOW_sum(sum(iif([Last week],[nb of posts],null))),0)
```

When I'm dragging my 'Last 7 days' calculation in my Rows shelf with the Country dimension It give me the same number for each country...

Why is that ?

Thanks !

Comment: What's your end goal here? Are you trying to get the number of posts per country for the last 7 days?

Comment: Yes. I'm applying the following tutorial http://www.vizwiz.com/2015/09/kpisandsparklines.html. The goal is to mix Sparkline and discrete value.

Comment: what does your "Last week" field look like?

Comment: Thanks. Here is my last week field : DATEDIFF('day',[Date],[Max date])<7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting it up like this should work:

1. Drag country column to the rows 2. Create Boolean last week calculated field {  date]> now()-7  }. Drag the calculated field to the Filters and select True to only show the last week of dates 3. Create another calculated field { countd(postid)  } and drag to columns.